# SQL Left Join Oddity

Tags: sql, left-join

Considering the following tables

```
sessions                   users
========                   =====
id uid sid                 id name
----------                 -------
7  1   192.168.0.10        1  AAA
8  2   NULL                2  BBB
12 2   192.168.0.13        3  CCC
15 20  NULL
```

Why is

```
SELECT u.name FROM `users` u 
LEFT JOIN sessions s 
ON u.id=s.uid 
WHERE s.sid IS NULL
```

returning

```
BBB
CCC
```

**Why is this retuning `CCC`** when the second uid is invalid. I was expecting NULL.
Please note that I do not want to fix the query, just to understand the result.

Comment: There is no uid  matching the id for CCC in the sessions table, so it will come back null, which matches your criteria. You have s.uid '2' in twice, change the uid for s.id '12' to a '3' and you will get expected results

Comment: u.id=s.uid,it does not satisfy to give your desired CCC

Comment: the condition `WHERE s.sid IS NULL` essentially says: give me those rows where **no** match is found in the sessions table. It's the same as `select * from users u where not exists (select * from sessions s where s.uid = u.id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the query is asking for is any users who do not have a session or who had a session that did not get assigned an s.sid value.

Comment: Back to SQL Sesame Street for me on this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a `LEFT JOIN` for this, because you do not care about non-matches:

```
SELECT u.name
FROM `users` u JOIN
     sessions s 
     ON u.id = s.uid 
WHERE s.sid IS NULL;
```

Comment: I do not need to fix the query, just to understand the output

Comment: Because you are using a `left join` that keeps all records in the first table.  Your `where` clause keeps the users that have no matches in the second table.